# AppDelegate.swift crashes macOS App

Tags: swift, macos, crash, runtime-error, appdelegate

When I try to launch my app, it simply crashes. The error it gives is `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000000ac0` and the error shows up at my AppDelegate.swift file on line 4. Here is the full AppDelegate.swift file:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate { //This is where I get the error

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

How do I fix this error? Thanks in advance,
Aaronjam

Answer (score 0):

After trying to fix the problem for over an hour, I deleted my target (after backing up my code, of course) and made a new one. Thanks for your help, @OverD!